# What is Unique thing of èvery device mobile in flutter device_info_plus package

Tags: flutter

I use flutter package device_info_plus.Please tell me what is unique thing in device which is different from every mobile.

'fingerprint':build.fingerprint,

https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/example

I try build.Fingerprint but in same indentical device its gives me same result. In android devices